# How can I validate an HTTP response?

Tags: http

I'm creating a low level HTTP server and I want to validate that my responses are correct.

Some of them are fine, but others fail. I have saved some responses as bytes and viewing them in HxD, and they *look* correct, but they obviously aren't in some way.

Here's the start of one HTTP response formatted as hex:

> 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 20 32 30 30 20 4F 4B 0D 0A 43 4F 4E 54 45 4E
> 54 2D 54 59 50 45 3A 20 69 6D 61 67 65 2F 70 6E 67 0D 0A 4C 41 53 54
> 2D 4D 4F 44 49 46 49 45 44 3A 20 53 75 6E 2C 20 30 31 20 4D 61 79 20
> 32 30 32 32 20 32 32 3A 32 34 3A 32 34 20 47 4D 54 0D 0A 41 43 43 45
> 50 54 2D 52 41 4E 47 45 53 3A 20 62 79 74 65 73 0D 0A 45 54 41 47 3A
> 20 22 37 35 37 35 35 33 36 61 61 35 64 64 38 31 3A 30 22 0D 0A 53 45
> 52 56 45 52 3A 20 4D 69 63 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2D 49 49 53 2F 31 30 2E
> 30 0D 0A 58 2D 50 4F 57 45 52 45 44 2D 42 59 3A 20 41 53 50 2E 4E 45
> 54 0D 0A 44 41 54 45 3A 20 57 65 64 2C 20 30 34 20 4D 61 79 20 32 30
> 32 32 20 30 39 3A 30 31 3A 34 38 20 47 4D 54 0D 0A 43 4F 4E 54 45 4E
> 54 2D 4C 45 4E 47 54 48 3A 20 39 38 37 35 37 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 6E 65 63
> 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 63 6C 6F 73 65 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 89 50 4E 47

How can I validate that the response I'm creating is valid according to [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)?

I'm working in .NET but I don't mind if it's an online tool or a different platform.

Edit:

I've solved my issue with this particular example (3 crlfs instead of 2 between head and body) but I'd still like to know how I can validate these requests automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up achieving this with [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpMachine.PCL/) and the following code:

```
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        using (var handler = new HttpParserDelegate())
        using (var parser = new HttpCombinedParser(handler))
        {
            parser.Execute(arr);
        }

        if (!handler.HttpRequestResponse.IsEndOfMessage)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"An HTTP response was serialized but it is not a valid response");
        }
    }
```